# JSON String remove characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array and I need to use the data in my application. I am calling it through javascript and I can iterate between the variables.

The problem I have, is the data isn't usable because of the '+' characters and the %2C etc.

```
"events":[{"url":"","name":"Test+Event2","location":"Some+little+village","eventDate":"Wednesday%2C+20th+August+2014+from+10%3A00+to+11%3A00"}
```

Is there a Javascript or JQuery solution to filter the strings?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is a URL Encoded JSON string. `var json_string = decodeURIComponent(uri_encoded_string)` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks! That works to remove the %2C etc, how would I remove the + ?

Comment: I've used the .replace function to replace the '+'